# Progress URL encoding

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

What's the best way to encode a URL in progress. I want to build an encoded URL and don't want to write my own encoding function. Is there a command that can be run or a function that someone else already wrote?

```
www.abc.com/the one/
```

to

```
www.abc/the%20one/
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp for the list of things that need to be encoded

Comment: I think you need to think about what you need to do. Or, if you already have, explain exactly what you want to do. The list you provide basically contains all characters. Do you, for instance, really want to encode "A" into "%41"?

Answer (score 1):

There is an article on the Progress website, which Google found me with very little effort...

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000042261

Note the disclaimers at the top of the article.

Comment: Thanks for including the amount of effort you expended... This solution will not work. The list on 'unsafe' character I need to worry about is much greater then what it provides. See the link in the question.